# Network traffic blocker by ip and port

Tags: command-line, network-manager, firewall

I'm getting continues traffic to my AWS ubuntu server. Those traffic increase my bandwidth billing in a high level. Is there any ip port blocker tool or a way to block those traffics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be more precise. Generally answer is to enable firewall.
Ubuntu buildin firewall is `ufw`

With command

```
 sudo ufw enable
```

you will block all inbound traffic. Then you can allow traffic from only one host on port `80` with command

```
sudo ufw allow from ip_address_of_host to any port 80
```

or allow only port 22 on server from any host

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```

on allow trafic from some network range

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24
```

For more complex rules you can also use `iptables`

Example, deny ping response to server with `iptables`

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -o eth0 -j ACCEPT          
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT     
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -s 0/0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT       
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -i eth0 -j DROP
```

To deny access from specific host you can add rule

```
 sudo ufw deny from ip_address_of_host to any
```

To deny access from host to port 80

```
  sudo ufw deny from ip_address_of_host to any port 80
```

To see status of `ufw`

```
  sudo ufw status numbered
```

To delete some rule, list first numbered and after delete with

```
  sudo ufw delete number_of_rule
```

You can insert rule before existing

```
  sudo ufw insert 1 deny from ip_address_of_host to any port 80
```

then

```
  sudo ufw insert 2 allow 80
```

Rules on this way will deny `ip_address_of_host` to access server on port `80`, but will allow any other

If you need more help, please comment my answer

Comment: Your answer is correct and working. Please edit the syntax error on "sudo insert" to "sudo ufw insert"

Comment: Done, TNX for comment